# which is better to store login state in an ASP.NET web-form application? session or DB field?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, session-state

i want to decide between using a session parameter like `Session["state"] = "logged";` or saving the state on my SQL server database ?
i also want to know is there any other way to save login state after i authorize a login ? because i have my special login code and its OK but is there any other way to store login state and retrieve it when user opens special pages ?

Comment: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You should use an existing security framework, and not build your own.

If you want to persist session information, you can persist it in a database. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604

You don't authorize a login, you *authenticate* it.

Comment: You don't slice a hair, you _split_ it. x